# Passing selected option to event handler on other element

Tags: angular

I have a `select` element and a button in an Angular 2 component. I have a click handler on the button, and when I click the button, I want to access the value of the `select` element. I have tried the following:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { Department } from "../classes/department";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: `
        <select #s>
            <option *ngFor="#department of departments" [value]="department">{{ department.id }}</option>
        </select>

        <button (click)="removeDepartment(s.value)">Remove</button>
    `
})
export class MyComponent {
    // ...

    removeDepartment(department: Department) : void {
        console.log(department);
        console.log(typeof department);
    }
}
```

Basically I have an array of `Department` objects, and when I click the button, I am trying to pass the object bound to the selected option to the `removeDepartment` method. I don't know if I can use the `s` variable as I am trying to do. The result is that the string `[object Object]` is passed to the method instead of the object.

I know that I can accomplish what I want with a `change` event on the `select` element, but I don't want to store the currently selected value within my component unless I have to. I could also go about it by using `@ViewChild`, but I prefer doing something similar to what I am trying to do, if possible.

Is it possible to pass the currently selected value by using a variable as I am trying to do, or do I have to keep a variable within my component and update it with a `change` event?

I am using Angular 2 beta 15.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use object as value you need to use `ngValue` instead of `value`. `value` only supports `string` and stringifies any value assigned to it:

```
<option *ngFor="let department of departments" [ngValue]="department">{{ department.id }}</option>
```

This was added in [beta.14](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta14-2016-04-07)

Comment: I was actually trying to get that to work because I read a bit about it. When I try to use `ngValue`, however, I get an error saying that the directory could not be found. I tried to add it to the `directives` key and import it, but my IDE doesn't seem to believe that it's available in `angular2/common` as `NgClass` is, for example. It seems as if it is not just my IDE, because I do also get a runtime error. Am I missing something here? Perhaps it is located somewhere else? Thanks! :-)

Comment: Thanks, it turned out that I made a mistake in my build. However, both in that Plunker and in my code, the passed value is a string and not an object as I had hoped for. Any idea why?

Comment: You need to use `[(ngModel)]="xxx"` or `(ngModelChange)="xxx=$event"` to get the object value. See https://plnkr.co/edit/mjm59Q?p=preview

Comment: Yes, but then I have to store the currently selected value in a property. What I was after was to pass it as an argument to the event handler to avoid keeping it in a variable. I don't know if it's possible, though?

Comment: I guess then you only have the option that `ngValue` also uses that you look up the object in your collection by the `id` you get from `s.value` already.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes, I did manage to get it work like that, although it is not the way I wanted to accomplish it. I was hoping there was a way to avoid having a variable keeping the current value, but I made a compromise in this case. Thanks!